# SQLite FullText Index search on 2 terms with AND & OR

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

I have created a Full Text Index and can search terms like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where myfield MATCH 'Food'
```

How do I add an AND clause to return records with the word FOOD and DOG ?

I've tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where myfield MATCH 'Food' and  myfield MATCH 'Dog'
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mytable where myfield = 'Food' and  myfield = 'Dog'`  ?

Comment: I wish to search using Full Text Search, the `Match` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield MATCH 'Food Dog'
```